# JWT authentication working with $http.get but not with $http.post

Tags: angularjs, node.js, jwt, mean, express-jwt

I am new to MEAN stack. 
I am using jwt to authenticate api endpoint ***'/api/candidates'***

In client-side/angular js service I have following entry

```
resumeFactory.get = function(candidateName) {
   return  $http.get('/api/candidates', {
      headers: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer '+ authenticationService.getToken()     
   });
};
```

on the server-side I have :

```
app.get('/api/candidates', auth, function (req, res) {
if (!req.payload._id) {
    //user not logged in
    console.log(req);
    res.status(401).json({"message": "no  user logged in from candidates"});
}
else {
    Candidate.find({}, function (err, candidates) {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
        }
        res.json(candidates);
    });
}
});
```

This works fine. i.e. **'auth'** is able to extract the token from the header

When i change everything to **post** instead of **get** :

on **client-side**

```
$http.post()
```

on **server side** :

```
app.post()
```

I get an error from jwt as following:

```
UnauthorizedError: No authorization token was found
```

Any suggestions on what is happening?. I can work with **get** but i want to know why **post** does not work

Comment: Check in Dev Tools if you really post that token in headers.

Comment: @Nonemoticoner I am unable to find that in Dev Tools. Not sure how to look for headers in the request

Comment: @ Nonemoticoner - I was finally able to figure out how to check headers Networks->XHR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `$http.post` config is the [third argument](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post), not second [(like in `get`)](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#get) so update your parameters accordingly:

```
$http.post('/url', { cool: postData }, {
  headers: {
    Authorization: 'Bearer '+ authenticationService.getToken()
  }    
});
```

Better yet, [use an interceptor](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors) to add the Authorization header to all requests.

Comment: Thanks Andy Gaskell.